# Changing root of tree and pruning

Tags: c, recursion, tree

I have an n-ary tree structure like what's explained in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122456/how-to-create-a-n-ary-tree-in-c):

```
typedef struct node {
    int ID;
    struct node *child;   // points to (first) child
    struct node *next;    // points to next node at same level (sibling)
    struct node *parent;  // points to parent
} node;
```

Nodes are created using `malloc`.

I want to write a function that will change the root of the tree to another (specified) node, and deallocate the memory of all the nodes that - because of the change of root - are no longer part of the tree (i.e. if a node can't be tracked back via parents to the new root, it should be set to `NULL` and its memory should be deallocated).

For instance, if this is my tree:

```
      1           
     / \
    2   3        
   / \    \
  4  5     6      
 / \
7   8
```

and I want to change the root from 1 to 3, then after calling the prune_tree function, the root will be 3 and the memory of every node other than 3 and 6 will have been deallocated.

The closest I have come to solving my problem involves this function:

```
void prune_tree(node **root, node *new_root) {
    if (*root == NULL || (*root)->parent == new_root)
        return;

    prune_tree(&((*root)->child), new_root);
    prune_tree(&((*root)->next), new_root);

    free(*root);
    *root = NULL;
}
```

and after calling this function I set

```
root = new_root;
```

I got here mostly by trial and error; in fact I'm not even sure why this works most of the time I test it. It also adds what's probably an unnecessary step of having to set the root to the new root address after calling the function. I assume there's a way I can modify the root address in the function, or return the new root address.

I would think I don't need to worry about memory usage since the function is deallocating memory, but a time-efficient function is preferable. I'm not sure if that means I should steer away from recursion or not...

Comment: For a way to return the new address, you can use a wrapper function that calls the recursive `prune_tree` & returns the new root. And then the wrapper function will be called  instead of the original `prune_tree`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work as you will be deallocating the new root itself. You only stop on nodes whose `parent` is the new root.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void prune_tree(node **root, node *new_root) {
    if (*root == NULL)
        return;
    if (*root == new_root) {
        (*root)->parent = NULL;
        return;
    }
    prune_tree(&(*root)->child, new_root);
    prune_tree(&(*root)->next, new_root);
    free(*root);
    *root = NULL;
}
```

You will still need to update the root of the tree to `new_root` after calling this function with its address:

```
prune_tree(&root, new_root);
root = new_root;
```

Comment: Thank you. After calling this function, will root = new_root, or will I have to set it to such afterwards?

Comment: don't you need to free up the memory allocated by the old tree elements that are no longer in the tree?

Comment: @user178831 No, `root != new_root`. This function does excatly what you did but only protects the new root's sub tree from removal in contract to what you did. So you need to do it afterwards in a wrapper function: `void wrapper_func(node **root, node *new_root){ prune_tree(root, new_root); *root = new_root; }`

Comment: & then call `wrapper_func` (From `main` or elsewhere) whenever you want to set the new root.

Comment: I see. I'm not 100% sure of this yet, but from testing it out, it seems like this function might not get rid of new_root's siblings (nexts) or their children.

Comment: @user178831 Yes, it is true i didn't notice that so quickly. The traversal stops whenever it reaches `new_root` because the function return before moving any further.

Comment: I posted an answer to my own question based off of @chqrlie's answer. I think it works...

Answer (score 0):

a recursive function would be perfect for this.

what you basically want to do (assuming there are no loops in the tree) is remove all the siblings of the new root, al their children and parents and al the parents of the root.

an algorithm could be:

```
typedef struct node {
    int ID;
    struct node *child;
    struct node *sibling;
    struct node *parent;
} node;

void remove_node(struct node* node, struct node* root)
{
    if(node->parent != NULL)
        remove_node(node->parent, new_root)

    if(node->sibling != NULL)
        remove_node(node->sibling, new_root)

    if((node->child != NULL) && (node->child != root))
        remove_node(node->sibling, new_root)

    free(node)
}

void prune_tree(node **root, node *new_root) {
    *root = new_root
    remove_node(new_root->parent);
    remove_node(new_root->sibling);
}
```

assumptions:

- new_root is in the tree
- no loops in the tree

Comment: This is logically similar to OP's recursive function and it must be wrong because you will eventually remove the new root's node.

Comment: i fixed it, you can remove the whole tree by setting node to NULL

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem with this updated answer as pointed to by OP. The traversal stops after reaching `new_root`. A new correct answer was added. Waiting for user @chqrlie to also approve changes for a better code version.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution...

```
void prune_tree(node** root, node* new_root)
{
    bool del = true;

    if (*root == NULL)
        return;

    if (*root == new_root) {
        del = false;
    }

    if (del){
        prune_tree(&(*root)->child, new_root);
        prune_tree(&(*root)->next, new_root);
        free(*root);
        *root = NULL;
    }
    else{
        prune_tree(&(*root)->next, new_root);
    }
}
```

Comment: The changes i suggested to @chqrlie's answer are logically equivalent to this but in more elegant way and without code redundancy. you could get ride of that ugly `if else` thing you did there because of that useless `del` variable. If @chqrlie approves the changes i suggested, you will see a better code.