# Structure of m-ary tree - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, tree

I have to implement some program in C, which parses details of a text file.
The first line of the text file is a number of nodes in m-ary tree.
The next lines represent the nodes this way: line number two in the text file may include: "1 2 3" and it actually says that the children of node number 0 (with key of 0) are 1 2 and 3. And the next line may include: "0 7 8" - and it says that the node with key of 1 has the children 0 7 8, and so forth... If some line consists of only "-" then it's a leaf.

Now, I am not sure how to define the struct which represents the nodes and which approach is better to use. I thought of defining (at run-time of course) an array of pointers to nodes (the number of nodes which we get at the very first line of the text). And in the struct of a node I thought maybe to declare on a pointer to pointer array which represent the possible children and father of a node - and with this array we would point to that array of nodes we have allocated at run-time. But I'm not sure it's a good practice and practical enough.

Do you have maybe any recommendations how can I improve my implementation way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a n-ary tree in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122456/how-to-create-a-n-ary-tree-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this guide [Binary tree introduction](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-1-introduction/)